# Using MemoryCache with HostFileChangeMonitor init to a directory gets ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: asp.net, memorycache

I am using MemoryCache from System.Runtime.Caching of .NET 4 and I wish to invalidate the cache entry when a directory changes.

HostFileChangeMonitor is supposed to handle both files and directories so I am adding it like so:

```
var cacheItemPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy { SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30) };
cacheItemPolicy.ChangeMonitors.Add(new HostFileChangeMonitor(new List<string> { folder }));
```

but then I get an exception:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
```

This only happens if I use the code in a ASP.NET website. It works fine from inside a console application.

I have found [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/721523/using-system-runtime-caching-memorycache-with-hostfilechangemonitor-init-to-a-non-existing-file-gets-argumentoutofrangeexception) on ms connect, but the directory I am adding to the HostFileChangeMonitor exists.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer my own question:
 it seems that 4.0 has a bug when adding Directories to the HostFileChangeMonitor.

Comment: My workaround was to add filedependencies on all the individual files of the Directory. My application also handled the addition and deletion of the files in the folder so it all worked out. As soon as it's fixed in the framework, I am gonna switch to directory monitor as it should be anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Even when watching for a single file the error still exists.
We are using HostFileChangeMonitor with a list of only one file and our client's Production server throws this exception.
We recommended the MS fix: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2346777
As soon as we can confirm the error is gone, i'll update the answer.