# UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000 error

Tags: c#, .net

```
List<string> directories = new List<string>() { rootSkinFolder };
directories.AddRange(Directory.GetDirectories(rootSkinFolder));
CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
policy.ChangeMonitors.Add(new HostFileChangeMonitor(directories));
policy.Priority = System.Runtime.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Default;
MemoryCache.Default.Set(cachePath, resultPath, policy);
```

I have code as above, but I am getting the error:

> The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between
>   year 0 and 10,000.

Please let me know what setting needs to be done to fix this error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using MemoryCache with HostFileChangeMonitor init to a directory gets ArgumentOutOfRangeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798498/using-memorycache-with-hostfilechangemonitor-init-to-a-directory-gets-argumentou)

Answer (score 1):

Try to look at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2346777.
It could help with your problem.

Comment: Link dead. Another solution?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13011779/155687